# Converting a pointer to a range

Tags: c++, c++20

This works:

```
const char* foo[] = {"This", "is", nullptr, "great"};
for (auto e : ::std::ranges::take_while_view (foo,             // <- array
                    ([](const char* s){return s!=nullptr;})))
      std::cout << e << "\n";
```

This doesn't:

```
const char* foo[] = {"This", "is", nullptr, "great"};
for (auto e : ::std::ranges::take_while_view (&foo[0],         // <- pointer
                    ([](const char* s){return s!=nullptr;})))
      std::cout << e << "\n";

error: no matching function for call to ‘take_while_view(const char**,
       main(int, char**)::<lambda(const char*)>)’
```

Can we, *using the standard library types and functions*, coerce C++ to treat a pointer as a kind of a semi-infinite range that we can then further restrict?

I can always create my own class to represent a semi-infinite view, but I'd rather find a solution in the standard library.

Comment: You can always create a (view) range type which represents a "semi-infinite range" that has this property. Though personally, I would not suggest making it implicitly convertible from a pointer type.

Comment: @NicolBolas yes I can create my own type, I meant the standard library types/functions. Updating....

Comment: There are solutions that could use standard library types, but they would require defining helper types for things like sentinels. Are those OK?

Comment: @NicolBolas Maybe, please show what you've got!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way to assemble such a range from disparate parts, but you cannot implicitly treat a `T*` as one.

What you have to do is construct a `subrange` from a pointer, using `unreachable_sentinel_t` as the sentinel type. So you could code such a function as:

```
template<typename T>
auto inf_ptr_range(T *ptr)
{
  return std::ranges::subrange(ptr, std::unreachable_sentinel_t{});
}
```

And you can [use that in your code](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hbePqj):

```
const char* foo[] = {"This", "is", nullptr, "great"};
for (auto e : ::std::ranges::take_while_view (
        inf_ptr_range(foo),
        ([](const char* s){return s!=nullptr;})))
    std::cout << e << "\n";
```

Or using view-style notation:

```
int main()
{
const char* foo[] = {"This", "is", nullptr, "great"};
for (auto e : inf_ptr_range(foo) | std::views::take_while(
        [](const char* s){return s!=nullptr;}))
    std::cout << e << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I think I like this one better than mine!

Answer (score 1):

Use `iota` to make an infinite range, then cut it off.

```
auto my_range =
    std::views::iota(&foo[0])
    | std::views::transform([](auto p) -> auto& { return *p; })
    | std::views::take_while([](auto p) { return p != nullptr; });

for(auto &ptr : my_range) {
    std::cout << ptr << "\n";
    ptr = "really";
}
for(auto &ptr : my_range) std::cout << ptr << "\n"; // mutation works!
std::cout << foo[3] << "\n";
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:33,endLineNumber:16,positionColumn:33,positionLineNumber:16,selectionStartColumn:33,selectionStartLineNumber:16,startColumn:33,startLineNumber:16),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cranges%3E%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++char+const+*foo%5B%5D+%3D+%7B%22This%22,+%22is%22,+nullptr,+%22great%22%7D%3B%0A++++auto+my_range+%3D%0A++++++++std::views::iota(%26foo%5B0%5D)%0A++++++++%7C+std::views::transform(%5B%5D(auto+p)+-%3E+auto%26+%7B+return+*p%3B+%7D)%0A++++++++%7C+std::views::take_while(%5B%5D(auto+p)+%7B+return+p+!!%3D+nullptr%3B+%7D)%3B%0A%0A++++for(auto+%26ptr+:+my_range)+%7B%0A++++++++std::cout+%3C%3C+ptr+%3C%3C+%22%5Cn%22%3B%0A++++++++ptr+%3D+%22really%22%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++for(auto+%26ptr+:+my_range)+std::cout+%3C%3C+ptr+%3C%3C+%22%5Cn%22%3B+//+mutation+works!!%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+foo%5B3%5D+%3C%3C+%22%5Cn%22%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:60.61719324026451,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g101,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-O3%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+10.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:49.34601664684899,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%231+with+x86-64+gcc+10.1%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50.65398335315101,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:39.38280675973549,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

I believe this is safe (that the `take_while` "guards" the `transform` and the `iota` so that we never try to compute `&foo[0] + 5` or even access `foo[3]`).